# Deleting user with federated authentication

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, saml-2.0, federated-identity

I am trying to use federated authentication (OAuth2 / SAML) in a web application. While federating authentication and possibly, authorization, how to deal with data of users who are deleted?

AFAIK there are no delete events propagated to applications from identity providers when a user is deleted.

Example: Deleting the data associated with user, when the account is deleted from external identity provider (Google, Facebook, or some enterprise identity server).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Federated authentication is about being able to authenticate a user based on an external system. It is not a way of tying user accounts in your system with the federated system. This means that there is no simple way of achieving what you need. E.g., you could build some custom integration with the federated identity provider or have a job that somehow verifies periodically whether the accounts from your system still exist externally.

In general, when using federated identity you shouldn't concern with whether the account still exists in the external system. The user uses that account to log in to your system, but your system maintains its own users.

Comment: Understood, thanks. But if user account is removed from external identity provider, the data associated with it will stay there forever in my system. How does large systems deal with this case when using social identity providers?

Comment: They don't. When a user creates an account in a system (even when using federated login), they need to consent to the policy of the given system. When they want to close that account, they have to do it in that given system. Deleting an account is not cascaded to other systems that happened to use federated login. The user will have to configure a new way to log in to that system, maybe with another federated identity.